# Why is the local density of states related to the retarded Green function?

Tags: condensed-matter, mathematical-physics, density-of-states

Consider a Hamiltonian $H$ acting on the single-particle Hilbert space $\mathscr{H}$ representing lattice sites, i.e., $|r\rangle$ forms an orthonormal basis of $\mathscr{H}$ where $r$ ranges over lattice sites. It's then easy to understand the **local density of states** at $r$ as the spectral measure $\mu_x (d\omega)$ of $|r\rangle$ with respect to Hamiltonian $H$, i.e., the "unique" measure such that
$$
\langle r| \frac{1}{H-z} |r \rangle = \int \frac{1}{\omega - z} d\mu_x (\omega)
$$
If $\mathscr{H}$ was finite-dimensional and $H$ is diagonalized by orthonormal basis $|n\rangle$ with energy $E_n$, then using theorems related to Herglotz functions (or by the equivalent relation $\mu_x(\omega) = \pi^{-1} \Im G(r,r,\omega+i0^+)$), it's easy to find that
$$
\mu_x(\omega)=\sum_n|\langle r|n\rangle|^2\delta(\omega-E_n)
$$

My question is that how is this concept generalized to Hamiltonian acting on the Fock space? I know that we can then define $\mu_x (\omega +i\epsilon)$ as the Fourier transform of
$$
\mu_x(t) = -\frac{1}{\pi} \Im G^\text{ret}(x,x;t), \quad G^\text{ret}(x,x;t) =-i\theta(t)\langle [c(x,t),c^*(x)]_{-z}\rangle
$$
where $G^\text{ret}$ is the retarded Green function and $z=\pm 1$ represents bosons/fermions. This way of defining $\mu_x(\omega)$ happens to allow the 2 definitions coincide in the case where $H$ was non-interacting, i.e., $H=\sum E_n c_n^* c_n$. However, in the more general case, what is the underlying **physical motivation**?